# any detailed doc about the supported Javascript API in the Android default browser?

Tags: android

I am desperately looking for a detailed documentation of the features supported by the Android browser and accessible from the JavaScript API, but still can't find any.

In particular, I would like details about:
-the extent of the html5 canvas implementation in Android wrt. the spec.
-the level of support of touch event and gesture event. (I found :
http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html -but it's 1 year old- 
and also the quirksmode.org site).

According to my tests, trapping multitouch event in JavaScript is not supported (in 2.2). But it would be easier to have an official doc than  a test-based approach.
-and to a more extent, the status of each HTML5 features in Android default browser.

Any good pointers ?

Thx

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript functionality available in a `WebView` or the Android browser is much the same as that available in other browsers - most of JavaScript 1.8 (see [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) for useful info).

If you use a `WebView` rather than just a page in a browser, then you can communicate between your Java application and your JavaScript running in your web-page (you can use JavaScript to call Java methods, and vice-versa); see [Using WebViews](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html).

The Android browser (or WebView) does not support multi-touch JavaScript events (see [Issue 11909](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909)).

You would have to implement your own touch handler in Java on your WebView, then pass the touch information to methods in your JavaScript.